# How to post pictures with the mobile app?

Tags: support, ios-app, images

How to post pictures with the mobile app?  I wanted to answer a question with a diagram on my mobile.  How should I do that?

I am currently on iPhone, using the Stack Exchange application.

If this feature is not present, I would like to request for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a Camera button when writing a post, which will let you choose between the iPhone's camera itself or the Photo Library.

[image]

<sub>(trivia: the screenshot was originally uploaded via the iPhone app)</sub>

You need to allow the Stack Exchange app to access your camera or photos, the app will ask you for this the first time you use this function.

Comment: Okay thanks!  Didn’t see that